# Bootstrap override not taking effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to override a bootstrap class using JavaScript. The problem is that value of display is changed by the Javascript code but the HTML rows aren't displayed. If I use !important in the style block in `custom.css` bootstrap is overridden and the JavaScript assignment is still the HTML rows aren't displayed....can anyone tell me whats wrong here. I did try using an ID then chaining the elements `(#id.class)` that didn't work either. (the code works fine without bootstrap)

**custom css**

```
body {
    margin-top:30px;
     }
 .hidden
  {
   display: none;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script> src="js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <table  class="hidden table table-striped table-border">

            <tbody>
                <tr class="hidden">
                 <td>List ............</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="hidden active">
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>  
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="well col-md-8">
      <p>Test Messages.........</p> 
     </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var count=4;

  var activerows=document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

    if(count <= activerows.length){
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
       {
       activerows[i].style.display="block";
       }
     }else
     {
        for (var i=0; i<activerows.length; i++) 
        {
          //  activerows[i].style.display='block';
         }
     }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using? as *Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3*

Comment: So the problem is this is not enough  activerows[i].style.display='block'; It is true?

Comment: omg why you making my life hard

Comment: I sure your code is only display 3 tr elements

Comment: Three tr should be displayed but none is...there are enough active rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Bootstrap* is the main culprit then don't use its class and simply use your *custom class* `hideme` or something and then override it using *Javascript* like I have done in this snippet below:

```js
var count = 4;

var activerows = document.getElementsByClassName("hideme"),
    tablehasClass = document.getElementById("table").classList;

if (count <= activerows.length) {
  tablehasClass.remove("hideme");
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    activerows[i].style.display = "table-row";
  }
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < activerows.length; i++) {
    //  activerows[i].style.display='';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.hideme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <table id="table" class="hideme table table-striped table-border">

          <tbody>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>List ............</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="hideme active">
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
              <th>D</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>5</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>7</td>
              <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>9</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideme">
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>19</td>
              <td>20</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="well col-md-8">
      <p>Test Messages.........</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

> table is very keen of its elements so never use `display: block` us `display: table-row` for `tr`, `display: table-cell` for `td` and similarly `display: table` for `table`

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay....this answer works for me but I am not sure what is  the purpose of this line " tablehasClass.remove("hideme");"....if its related to when count=0 then this would not be necessary since this code would not be called....please explain this line of code

Comment: @MichaelE I have set the `table` to be hidden by default and whenever your `if (count <= activerows.length) {...` condition turns to be true it will remove the `hideme` class and makes the `table` visible.

Comment: interesting! .....removing the line doesn't actually keeps the table invisible...just not properly formed. I understand now what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the style from javascript you should remove the class from the element. 
**Alternatively you can set the cssText of the element style to `display:block !important`**

```js
var count=4;

  var activerows=document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

    if(count <= activerows.length){
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
       {
         activerows[i].style.cssText = 'display:block !important';
       }
     }else
     {
        for (var i=0; i<activerows.length; i++) 
        {
          //  activerows[i].style.display='block';
         }
     }
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:30px;
     }
 .hidden
  {
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <table  class="hidden table table-striped table-border">

            <tbody>
                <tr class="hidden">
                 <td>List ............</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="hidden active">
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>  
                    <th>C</th>
                    <th>D</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="well col-md-8">
      <p>Test Messages.........</p> 
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Never encourage anyone to use `!important` its a horrible thing

Comment: I am not interested in using !important

Comment: In that case the good option would be to either use a custom class instead of bootstrap `hidden` class which sets the display to none without the `!important` and then toggle its display using js. Or else you can very well remove the css class `hidden` from the element in order to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this row

```
activerows[i].style.display="block";
```

with

```
$(activerows[i]).attr("style", "display: block !important");
```

or

```
$(activerows[i]).removeClass('hidden');
```

You need !important again to override the previous !important.
https://jsfiddle.net/nqtafyg2/6/

Comment: Never encourage anyone to use `!important` its a horrible thing

Comment: Using important does work...at least when used in custom.css.,  but I am trying to stay away from it

Comment: @MichaelE That's why I added two option. You can use the second one.